How to perform load testing for a GraphQL endpoint that uses persited queries
I have an application that receives frequent updates. It uses persisted queries to communicate with GraphQL endpoint. How can I write efficient and maintainable load tests without having to modify hashes every time the app updates? I prefer using k6, but perhaps you know of a more efficient tool for this case.

If the query doesn't change - the hash doesn't change, you should be able to use the same payloads, but it assumes that the system under doesn't discard saved hashes during update (and in my opinion it shouldn't otherwise all clients won't be able to get the data after the update).
The options are in:

use "normal" GraphQL queries instead of hashes
pre-generate hashes from the queries somewhere in setUp phase, normally they're one-way hash functions like SHA-2
get new hashes from the system under test database, see How to Retrieve Database Data for API Testing with JMeter for more information about the concept

